# How to use touch event to instead of click event on mobile website

Tags: iphone, web, click, touch

It seems that click event have delay on website on iphone, but the `touchstart` or `touchend` could response correctly, but how to use the only `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` to simulate `click` event? or even simulate the long press event on a website on iphone?

I think I can't bind the click handler directly to the `touchstart` or `touchend` event, one situation is that when the user press on the screen , fire the touchstart event , but if he don't want a click event, how can he cancel it, either I can't bind the handler to the touchend event.

So how can I simulate the click event with touchstart and touchend event?Is there conflict or something should I mentioned?Is there some post or article talk about how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a chrome extension for this purpose. It translate mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events to touchstart, touchmove, touchend. It actually simulate iphone5.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/touchphone-simulator/jijkpkhmnpbecppjhicgegndbbgfnngf

I use phantom-limbs.js. If you want more functions like gesture(which i excluded in my extension), visit brian's github.

https://github.com/brian-c/phantom-limb